# How to offset limit by sorted index with AQL?

Tags: sorting, arangodb, aql

I have a document collection of `member`s which have two relevant properties: `_key` and `score`. I've also created a `persistent` index on the `score` field, as that should make sorting significantly faster. I want to write an AQL query that returns different results based on the sorted index of a specific member (referred to as A):

- Always returns at least the top 5 members by `score`. (`LIMIT 5`)
- If A is in the top 10, return the 6 - 10 ranked members. (`LIMIT 5, 5`)
- Otherwise, return the members directly above and below A in rank. (`LIMIT x - 1, 3`, x = A's rank)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to do this in a single query, however I was able to fetch the rank of a member by doing something along the lines of

```
RETURN LENGTH(
  FOR m IN members
    FILTER m.score > DOCUMENT("members", "ID").score
    RETURN 1
) + 1
```

and then use a second query to fetch the ranked data I wanted, something like

```
  FOR m IN members
    SORT m.score DESC LIMIT 10
    RETURN m
```

or joining two sub-queries with `LIMIT 5` and `LIMIT rank - 2, 3` depending on the rank.